# Error getting SQL Server database out of recovery mode?

Tags: sql-server, set, recovery, reportserver

I have a SQL Server database in recovery status this is the script i used to try to get it out of recovery mode:

```
--Step 1 (Check Database Status) 
SELECT 
    DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('CM_DSS', 'status') AS '"CM_DSS Current Status"', 
    DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('ReportServer', 'status') AS '"ReportServer Current Status"',
    DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('ReportServerTempDB', 'status') AS '"ReportServerTempDB Current Status"',
    DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('SUSDB', 'status') AS '"SUSDB Current Status"'

--Step 2 (Set Database into Single User Mode)
ALTER DATABASE ReportServer SET Single_User

--Step 3 (Set Database in Emergency Mode)
ALTER DATABASE ReportServer SET EMERGENCY

--Step 4 (Repair Missing Log File with Dataloss  
DBCC CHECKDB('ReportServer', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)

--Step 5 Set Database Access for Everyone 
ALTER DATABASE ReportServer SET MULTI_USER
```

This is the error I get back after trying to run step 2 :

> Msg 5011, Level 14, State 9, Line 2
>   User does not have permission to alter database 'ReportServer', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.
>
> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

I am sure I have admin rights to this db , if not how do I check? Because the ReportServer database does exist it is just in recovery mode..

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER DATABASE [database_name] 
SET SINGLE_USER 
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

should kick everyone else off so it can change to single user mode

To check what your rights are,

```
use [database_name]
select *
from sys.fn_my_permissions (NULL,'DATABASE')
```

and you need to have ALTER rights on the database to use SET on the database

Example:
[image: Rights list with Alter highlighted]

Comment: When I type the script to check my rights i get this error "Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
The server principal "DCSS\Austin.Holmes" is not able to access the database "SUSDB" under the current security context."

Comment: Are you using the word DATABASE in the select? You must have that word for the select to work.

Comment: added picture of results you should see - if you don't see these, then you don't have many rights